# Fahrenheit to Celsius converter is there a better way?

Tags: actionscript-3

Here i have a AS3 Fahrenheit to Celsius converter i am wondering is there a better way to complete the same function keeping in mind this dose work for the time being?
<< While only having 2 decimal places. >>

```
function RandomNumber(min:Number, max:Number = 0):Number
{
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

for(var i:int = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    var fahrenheit:Number = RandomNumber(-50, 100)

    function fahrenheit2celsius(fahrenheit):Number
    {
        var celsius:Number = fahrenheit
        celsius = fahrenheit - 32
        celsius = celsius / 1.8
        celsius = celsius * 10 ^ 2
        celsius = celsius + .5
        celsius = celsius / 10
        return(celsius)
    }

    trace(fahrenheit + " fahrenheit",fahrenheit2celsius(fahrenheit) + " celsius",)
}
```

Comment: You should not declare your `fahrenheit2celsius()` function in your `for` loop. Moreover, event if `;` are not always required, never use them can be source for bugs. And why write `10 ^ 2` instead of `100` as it would be clearer. Finally method names should start with a lowercase character to help differentiating them from class names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not this:

```
function fahrenheit2celsius(fahrenheit):Number
{
    var celsius:Number = (5/9)*(fahrenheit-32);
    return Math.round(celsius); // <-- if you want to round to nearest int ?
}
```

Comment: Yes. But will it work with a separate function to give 2 decimal places.

Comment: you want two decimal places of precision, is that what you're asking?

Comment: @ScottAllen That's controlled when converting the *number* to a *string representation* (for display). See [`Number.toFixed`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Number.html#toFixed()).

Comment: yes. but will not round to a whole number.

Comment: @ScottAllen - I modified the answer to round to the nearest whole number.  Is that what you were looking for ?

Comment: No. if you run the version i have made it will round to two decimal places but is of by a few decimal to what he answer should be.

Comment: Thats because `^` is a bitwise operator. It isn't actually equaling 100. 10^2 = 8